# Decrementing foreign key after primary key deletion SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

SQL Noob here. I am designing a GPS-tracker application and have two tables; a track descriptor table and a track data table. The track descriptor table has the primary key (autoincrement) and the track data table has the foreign key. I would like that after I delete a row from descriptor table, all keys greater than that key are decremented by 1 (does autoincrement do this?). I would also like the same thing to happen in the data table, where all keys greater than deleted are decremented.
I am developing for Android and have know how to do it by this method: [How do I add and subtract numbers in SQLite for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302548/how-do-i-add-and-subtract-numbers-in-sqlite-for-android) . But this seems very resource intensive, is there any way to do the same thing at Table creation (triggers)? 
Here is the declaration of the two tables (sorry for the Java!!!):

```
// TRACK_DESCRIPTION table create statement
        String createTableTrackDescription =
                "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_TRACK_DESCRIPTION + "("
                        + Constants.COL_TRACK_DESC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + Constants.COL_TRACK_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + Constants.COL_LOCATION + " TEXT)";
        // TRACK_DATA table create statement
        String createTableTrackData =
                "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_TRACK_DATA + "("
                        + Constants.COL_TRACK_DATA_ID + " INTEGER,"
                        + Constants.COL_LATITUDE + " REAL,"
                        + Constants.COL_LONGITUDE + " REAL,"
                        + Constants.COL_SPEED + " REAL,"
                        + Constants.COL_ALTITUDE + " INTEGER,"
                        + Constants.COL_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER,"
                        + "FOREIGN KEY(" + Constants.COL_TRACK_DATA_ID + ") REFERENCES "
                        + Constants.TABLE_TRACK_DESCRIPTION + "(" + Constants.COL_TRACK_DESC_ID + "))";
```

Comment: Auto increment does not do this; and yes, doing so can be costly; which is why it is usually discouraged.

Comment: Why you want change the FK id? You shouldnt btw

Comment: Also, Sqlite != MySql

Comment: okay, so from what I understand - I should let the keys roam free, so if I have for example 15 entries/PKs(1-15) and I delete PK 10, I should not try to decrement 11-15 to fill the hole?

Comment: @ShaneMonksO'Byrne correct. There usually turns out to be very little real world need to have the numbers contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does autoincrement do this?

No, in fact coding **`AUTOINCREMENT`**, restricts the re-use of unused **rowids**.

SQLite creates a unqiue identifier, the **rowid**, for every row unless you specify **`WITHOUT ROWID`**. This identifier is known as the **rowid**.

If you code **`column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`** then **column_name** is an alias for the **rowid** *(e.g. `CREATE TABLE x (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, another_column TEXT)` creates table x with 2 columns, column **_id** is an alias of the **rowid**)*

The **rowid** will be a higher value (first it is **1**) generally the next so normally 1,2 etc, unless the highest number has been used `9223372036854775807` in which case **`AUTOINCREMENT`** if coded or not is considered as follows :-

If **`AUTOINCREMENT`** has been coded (i.e `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`). **`AUTOINCREMENT`** guarantees a higher **rowid**, so once `9223372036854775807` has been reached an [SQLITE_FULL](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#full) exception is raised; and

- *if you force an insertion using the value `9223372036854775807` for an alias of **rowid** where **AUTOINCREMENT** has been coded, then the SQLITE_FULL exception will occur if another insert is attempted.*

Without **`AUTOINCREMENT`** SQLITE randomly selects an unused **rowid** *(e.g. your deleted row)*.

The **`AUTOINCREMENT`** keyword thus ensures that **rowid**'s will be larger.

- It is when `WITHOUT ROWID` is not coded that causes a unique generally incrementing column as the **rowid**.
- It is the use of `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` that creates an alias for the **rowid**.
- The **rowid** is not normally visible i.e. `SELECT *`, will not include the **rowid** column. However; it would include an alias of the **rowid**.
- You can include the **rowid** by specifying it as a column e.g. `SELECT rowid, *` *(the **rowid** and all other columns)*.
- Coding the **`AUTOINCREMENT`** keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.

---

You may wish to look at:-

- [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)
- [Rowid Tables](https://sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)