# Reset incremented value of rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 10 rows. Each row has an id, name and a year. Each id has a value that is incremented by 3 from the previous value. For example, the first row has an id of 1, then the next has an id of 4 etc.

After deleting the first 9 rows, the next row I added instead of having an id of 4, it continued from 31.

How can I reset the value of the next added row to start from 4 (or the last value incremented by 3)?

Comment: How are you incrementing the value by 3 in the first place? Is the id column in your database set to auto_increment? Need some code here, we are not going to guess and read your mind how you have this setup ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrementing foreign key after primary key deletion SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838907/decrementing-foreign-key-after-primary-key-deletion-sqlite). In particular, my last comment on the question applies.

Comment: Decrementing and/or reshuffling auto id's is dangerous (and generally pointless/unnecessary); especially when the increment amount is not 1, as that often is used to prevent overlap when integrating data from multiple databases.

Comment: This is a really bad idea.

Comment: You can't set `AUTO_INCREMENT` lower than the current maximum. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a `FUNCTION` that calculates the new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for `id` field of a `test` table by a user defined `step`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test`(`step` INT) RETURNS int(11)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
IF `step`<1 THEN
SET `step` = 1;
END IF;
RETURN `step`+(SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `test`);
END
```

You can use a function like that to calculate the new value for the `id` (`AI`) field when inserting new rows to the table.
For example.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE `test` (`id`,`value`) VALUES ((SELECT `test`(4)),'yourvalue');
```